# How to know if a class is compiled with openjdk or sunjdk?

Tags: java, saxon

I want to use some thirdparty jars like saxonica in my product. Earlier we used to use Oracle JDK. Now, we are removing Oracle JDK to use OpenJDK. Can I use the same jar.

In this context, I want to know if my jar is built with Oracle JDK or OpenJDK ? How can I know it ?

Comment: In general, you can't.

Comment: The entire point of having the extensive JVM Specification is so that jars are portable between JVM implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question "Saxon": Saxonica currently builds issued JAR files using the Oracle JDK, though this may change in the future because of Oracle's licensing changes. If we do switch, there should be no way users can tell the difference.

The level of compatibility between different JVMs is so high that we don't even bother testing on multiple JVMs. I don't recall ever having a bug where things worked on one JVM and not on another. Of course, you need to use a JVM/JDK in the right version range: Saxon 9.8 works with Java 6 and later, Saxon 9.9 with Java 8 and later.

@StephenC talked about vendor policies concerning which platforms are supported and which aren't. In Saxonica this has never been a binary supported/not-supported decision. If you find a problem that we can reproduce in the lab then we will try and fix it if we can; if you find a problem that you can only reproduce by using some exotic platform, then we'll tell that we can't fix it: but that doesn't mean you are "unsupported". The same applies to the "and later" in the Java version -- you're welcome to use Saxon with Java version 17 on the day it is released, and if you find say that using the Japanese calendar no longer works, then we'll take note of the fact; we won't necessarily fix it, but we won't tell you the product (or the customer, or the platform) is unsupported.

Answer (score -1):

It really doesn't matter whether the class was compiled with OpenJDK or Sun / Oracle JDK.  The Java bytecode compilers in a given release of OpenJDK and the corresponding release of Oracle JDK should produce identical code<sup>1</sup>, if called with equivalent options, etcetera.  The compilers are build from the same source code tree.

Besides, as far as I am aware, OpenJDK and Oracle JDK compilers don't put this information into compiled classes.  And a deep dive of the source tree of OpenJDK / Oracle JDK 8 confirms this.  There are no relevant undocumented attributes emitted by the standard javac compilers<sup>3</sup>.

---

> Can I use the same (3rd-party) jars?

Yes.  It should make no difference that the classes in a JAR have been compiled with OpenJDK versus Oracle JDK.

The caveat though is Java *versions*.  If a 3rd-party jar file supports (say) Java 7 and you tried to use it with Java 8 (OpenJDK or Oracle) then you may run into trouble, and you may need to use a newer version of the jar.  Check the support site for the libraries that you depend on<sup>2</sup>.

And ... of course ... you should be testing your application thoroughly to identify any problems that might (hypothetically) be attributable to changing to OpenJDK.

---

<sup>1 - The files might not be byte-for-byte identical because the bytecode compilers add a couple of undocumented attributes containing source and target file timestamps.  It is possible to suppress this when compiling.</sup>

<sup>2 - You might find that a library vendor will only certify their library for Oracle JDK.  If you find that, you should probably talk to them directly to understand the reasons for this, and the implications for your use of the library.  This could only be a short term issue.  (If a vendor refused to support either OpenJDK or Oracle JDK in the long term, they would be liable lose a substantial percentage of their customers.)</sup>

<sup>3 - I vaguely recall that the old GNU Jikes compiler used to put other non-standard attributes into the ".class" file to identify the compiler, but that won't help you distinguish Oracle JDK and OpenJDK compilers.</sup>

Comment: Somebody seems to think that this is wrong.  I have no idea why.